# Python If error exist then ignore and keep going with the rest of the code

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I made the following code that consumes multiple reports on a specific folder:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

##some code before

all_files = glob.glob("CONTROL_REPORT*")
lib = []

for filename in all_files:
     df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
     lib.append(df)

ap_control = pd.concat(lib, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
ap_control = ap_control[['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5']]

##some code after
```

However there are instances that the control_report doesn't exist on the folder hence I would like to add an exception that if there's an error on this part of the code to ignore and keep going with the rest of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use try-except statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [try--catch---exceptio](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)n block

```
for filename in all_files:
     try:
         df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
     except:
         continue
     lib.append(df)
```

Comment: nice, that was what I was looking for, I was trying to do an if but completely forgot about the the try catch. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Try-Except statement for this

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Regards